# How to copy paste drawing canvas with resizing in Word

Tags: angular, typescript, office-js

We're trying to achieve a built-in functionality that Word does using Office-JS but were wondering if it's possible.

We have two drawing canvases, one is larger, contains several images and shapes. And the other one is smaller and is empty.

In Word, we can go to the large drawing canvas, press CTRL+A to select all contents inside the canvas, then go to the other smaller drawing canvas and simply paste it and everything will be resized automatically.

We're trying to automate this process but it doesn't give us the same result. Using Office-JS API, we get the OOXML of the canvas, then we use context.document.body.insertOoxml to insert that OOXML into the new canvas, the contents are inserted but it doesn't do the resize automatically to fit the smaller canvas.

Is there any other way to accomplish that?

Here's what we tried, looping through each element in the canvas and resize it to a new size, but it doesn't seem to be reflecting the changes:

```
        // Get all paragraphs 
        let xmlContent;
        xmlContent = doc.body.getOoxml();
        await context.sync();

        const parser = new DOMParser();
        let xml: Document = parser.parseFromString(xmlContent.value, 'application/xhtml+xml');
        const paragraphs = xml.getElementsByTagName('w:p');

  for (let i = 0; i <= paragraphs.length - 1; i++) {
            if (paragraphs[i].getElementsByTagName('w:sdtPr').length > 0
              && paragraphs[i].getElementsByTagName('w:sdtPr')[0].getElementsByTagName('w:id')[0].getAttributeNode("w:val").value === '1234306') {
              targetCanvasParagraph = paragraphs[i + 1];
           }
    let drawings = targetCanvasParagraph.getElementsByTagName('w:drawing');
                let factor = 1.724156661532341;
                for (let i = 0; i < drawings.length; i++) {
                  let positionH = drawings.item(i).getElementsByTagName('wp:positionH')[0];
                  if (positionH) {
                    let posOffsetH = positionH.getElementsByTagName('wp:posOffset')[0];
                    posOffsetH.textContent = (Math.trunc(Number(posOffsetH.textContent) / factor)).toString();
                  }
    
                  let positionV = drawings.item(i).getElementsByTagName('wp:positionV')[0];
                  if(positionV){
                    let posOffsetV = positionV.getElementsByTagName('wp:posOffset')[0];
                    posOffsetV.textContent = (Math.trunc(Number(posOffsetV.textContent) / factor)).toString();
                  }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this. May be you can try to fetch and set the size of canvas rather than each elements.